# Setting end point in mouseDragged and using it in mousePressed

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a program in which you can draw (lines, ovals, or rectangles) on a panel and specify colors, width, fill, etc. I have a JPanel class that implements a MouseMotionListener and MouseListener.

This is the code for the mouseDragged method:

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
   pointEnd = e.getPoint();
   repaint();
}
```

This is the code for the mousePressed method:

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 

    Paint c = window.getFirst();
    second = window.getSecond();

    int shapeOption= window.getShapeSelect();
    //System.out.println(shapeOption);
    boolean fill = window.getFilled();

    BasicStroke s = new BasicStroke(window.getLineWidth()); //may not need new BasicStroke()

    pointStart = e.getPoint();

    Shape temp;


    switch (shapeOption) {
        case 0: 
           temp = new Line(pointStart, pointEnd, s, c);
        case 1: 
           temp = new Rectangles(pointStart, pointEnd, s, c, fill);
        default: 
           temp = new Oval(pointStart, pointEnd,s,c, fill);
    }

    shapes.add(temp);

}
```

I have two issues with this program. The switch statement doesn't work as expected. Even though shapeOption is updating correctly it only uses the default case. I get the warning "The assigned value is never used" for new Line and new Rectangle.

The other issue I am having is that the program only draws little points. I believe it is because it creates the shape when the mouse is pressed, at which point pointEnd is the same as pointStart. How can I make it so that pointEnd is not passed until after the mouseDragged method has been complete?

I hope this makes sense, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget use of `break;` in your switch statement! Otherwise you'll always default to the default statement. Closing question as a duplicate.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `mousePressed` occurs before `mouseDragged` and `mouseReleased` , so using `pointEnd` in `mousePressed` is completely pointless

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you. I can't believe I couldn't figure that out after all the time I spent looking at it. But that doesn't solve the second issue.

Comment: **public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {** not showing in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To your two questions:

1) You need `break;` at the end of each case statement; otherwise, control will be passed through all of your case statements, and `temp` will always be set to an `Oval`.

2) `mousePressed()` gets called before `mouseDragged()`. You should do the drawing either in `mouseDragged()` to make it live, or `mouseReleased()` to do it only when the shape is finished. You may also need a flag to check that the mouse has moved sufficiently far between `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` so that you don't draw points on click events that aren't drags.